# C: main not found, but it's there | Compilation error

Tags: c++, c, compilation, terminal, makefile

When I compile two .c files like given below I get a really weird error.

Code for compiling on terminal

```
  gcc -I. -o main.c matrix.c -lblas -lgfortran
```

Error:

```
  /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
  /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
  /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
  /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
  /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
  /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
  /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
  ...
```

I did a bit of reading and the solution seems to be to add a main file. But I know for a fact I had the main.c file with the int main() in it before compiling. 
Here's the list of everything before compiling:

```
  > ls
  errors.txt  main.c  main.c~  matrix.c  matrix.c~  matrix.h  matrix.h~
```

After compilation this is the list of everything present:

```
  > ls
  errors.txt  main.c~  matrix.c  matrix.c~  matrix.h  matrix.h~
```

For some reason my main.c is getting deleted everytime I compile. What's weird is everything was working perfectly till a couple of minutes ago. Can someone help?

Comment: `-o main.c` asks it to *overwrite* `main.c` with the object created by compiling matrix.c and linking blas and gfortran.  Try e.g. ...`-o main main.c`... to generate a program called `main`.

Answer (score 14):

```
gcc -I. -o main.c matrix.c -lblas -lgfortran
```

the `-o main.c` tells the compiler to write its compiled output into the file main.c, which is probably not what you want.  You probably want:

```
gcc -I. -o progname main.c matrix.c -lblas -lgfortran
```

Answer (score 7):

`-o main.c` means the result of the compilation should be written to `main.c` (default is something like `a.out`). This is definitely not what you intended, and `main.c` is being deleted since the compilation fails.

If you meant "turn on optimizations", it's `-O` (uppercase).

Comment: shoot! Damn that was fairly stuipd of me :|
Thank You :)

Answer (score 2):

-o Option lets the c compiler save the compiled code in the file whose name is immediately after -o option

By default in the gcc  compiler in unix save the compiled out put in a.out file

with -o option we can make it save in desired_filname.out file